# Next.js: How to ensure only one instance of a module?

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have a Next.js app with a very simple database using [lowDb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb). The idea was to have one module with a simple `get` and `set` functions, and inside a module, a db is set as a top level constant:

```
const dbAdapter = new JSONFile(dbFile)
const db = new Low(dbAdapter)

let randomId = generateRandomId()
console.log(`DB: Using database in ${dbFile}, instance ${randomId}`)

/// A promise we call at the beginning of get and set functions to ensure db is initialized
let initPromise = new Promise<undefined>(async function(resolve, reject){       
    console.log(`DB: init, reading database ...`)

    // Read data from JSON file, this will set db.data content
    await db.read()

    // If file.json doesn't exist, db.data will be null
    // Set default data, node >= 15.x
    db.data ||= {
        tracks: {},
    }

    resolve(undefined)
})

export async function getTracks() {
    await initPromise
    return db.data['tracks']
}

...
```

The `getTracks()` is then called inside `getServerSideProps` function of multiple routes  to provide actual data to both SSR and client rendered page.

The problem seems to be that as I use the database in multiple pages, Next.js is instantiating this module multiple times, leading to each page having its own separate database (so whatever one page saves, the other one doesn't see, as each instance keeps it's own in-memory cache, and doesn't re-read the db file on every read).

Here is what the log shows:

```
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 100 ms (387 modules)
DB: Using database in tracks.json, instance tpzoj
DB: init, reading database ...
```

Then I navigate to another page, and this happens - a module is built again for another page's bundle, and another instance of db is created:

```
wait  - compiling /edit (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 115 ms (394 modules)
DB: Using database in tracks.json, instance gjndv
DB: init, reading database ...
```

Is there a way to force Next.js to only build a certain module once (instead of bundling it into each page separately)?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10933 - basically the takeaway seems to be "avoid in-process memory cache", and use filesystem or redis instead :(.

Or, in my case wait for `db.read()` inside every `getTracks()`, to force re-read of a db on every request :(. Is there a better way?

Comment: Probably you can get it working using next.js with [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server). However it may be easier to change DB (sqlite for example) and keep all the features offered by next